# ffmpeg combine existing filter_complex with upscaleto e.g. 720p

Tags: video, filter, ffmpeg, youtube, mp4

Currently I am combining two videos using this filter:

```
-filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=main_w:ih[sec][pri]; [sec]setsar=1,drawbox=c=black:t=fill[sec];[pri][sec]hstack[canvas]; [canvas][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w"
```

The output is the following: [test.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF6cN.png) (Green is the first video input, orange the second one) The whole video (red) has a format of 1600x540 (That might change depending on the input sizes.)

My question is whether there is a way to upscale this video to maybe 1920x1080 or 1280x720 in the same command. By upscaling I mean to change its size and to fittingly insert black bars on the side/top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a scale and pad after the overlay.

`[canvas][1:v]overlay=main_w-overlay_w,scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:-1:-1"`